# Are there any MVC Razor T4 templates available for download?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4

I know that I can create my own T4 tempates for creating pages for Edit, Detials, Edit, etc. but I would like to download some new ones that have already been created.  Are there any out there available for (preferably free) download?

Comment: are you asking about MVC razor templates or T4 templates? they are very different. What you are asking appears to me to be unrelated to T4 completely.

Comment: I am asking about T4 tempates - ones that will generate views in Razor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MVCScaffolding? You can get it via Nuget.

[blog about MVCScaffolding](http://rachelappel.com/ready-set-scaffold-build-asp.net-mvc-3-applications-quickly-with-mvcscaffolding)